# Spring security: Is there a way to secure one endpoint in two filter chains?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have two types of users: say, admins and users. Users are authenticated by http basic, and admins are authenticated by jwt.
So, I have such configurations in two @Configuration:

```
http.cors().and.csrf().disable().and().antMatcher("**/user/**")
            .httpBasic();
```

and

```
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("**/admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

But I have some endpoints (say, /data), which are need to be accessible(secured!) by users and administrators both. Is there a way to configure something like this, or do I need to divide /data endpoints?

Comment: You can configure filters for specific endpoints as well. You can write custom code in those filters and handle any custom logic. Other option would be to use AOP on api function itself and do custom handling there.

Comment: This is good suggestion and worked for me like a charm, I didn't think about it. Please, post it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure filters for specific endpoints as well. You can write custom code in those filters and handle any custom logic. Other option would be to use AOP on api function itself and do custom handling there.